# How to figure out the road assignment of gps points for a route?

Tags: google-maps

Just wondering if there is a map matching API in google map/osm given a gpx file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "reverse geocoding" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding).

Of course there are services like google (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding) but you can found some open or free project.

Take a look to:
http://www.geonames.org/
and
http://openaddresses.org/